# Where is $form_state stored between form build, and form submit functions?

Tags: forms

I assume that $form_state data can normally be stored either in the database, or in the session.

In this code:

```
function _module_name_main_form($form, $form_state) {
  $form_state['random_extra_data'] = some_func();
}

function _module_name_main_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
  $important_data = $form_state['random_extra_data'];
}
```

I trust that there are limits to how the user can manipulate `$form_state`, which isn't true if `$form_state['random_extra_data']` is stored in the session.

Is that safe to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cache_form` table stores `$form_state`, so except for the values passed on by the client, which should be validated anyway, it is safe to trust the content in $form_state.